# Snowflake - Processing aborted due to error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

i am getting error while calling below procedure

```
create or replace procedure get_net_profit_based_on_partition_value(part_value varchar)
returns table (branch_id integer, city varchar, net_profit float, net_profit_part float )
language sql
as
declare
    res resultset default (select branch_id, city,net_profit, 100 * ratio_to_report(net_profit) over (partition by :part_value) as net_profit_part from store_sales order by city);
begin 
    return table(res);
end;
```

and when calling the procedure

```
call get_net_profit_based_on_partition_value('city');
```

Getting below error:

```
000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300002:3405954919; incident 7068082.
```

I already checked that this select statement alone would work, but its failing in the procedure

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Because your input variable is referencing an object, not a value, I think you need to use the keyword "identifier" e.g.

```
res resultset default (select branch_id, city,net_profit, 100 * ratio_to_report(net_profit) over (partition by identifier(:part_value)) as net_profit_part from store_sales order by city);
```